# I got error AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram, openai-api

I got error when running python script to integrate openai with telegram bot. here is my code:

```
# Import the necessary modules
import telegram
import openai
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Updater
from queue import Queue

# Initialize the Telegram bot
bot = telegram.Bot(token='')

# Initialize the OpenAI API
openai.api_key = ''

# Define a function to handle /start command
def start(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hi! I'm a ChatGPT bot. Send me a message and I'll try to respond to it.")

# Define a function to handle messages
def message(bot, update):
    # Get the message text
    message_text = update.message.text

    # Call the OpenAI API to generate a response
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="davinci",
        prompt=message_text,
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.5,
    )

    # Get the response text from the API
    response_text = response.choices[0].text.strip()

    # Send the response back to the user
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=response_text)

# Initialize the Telegram bot updater and dispatcher
update_queue = Queue()
updater = Updater(bot=bot, update_queue=update_queue)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Add command handlers
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

# Add message handler
message_handler = MessageHandler(None, message)
dispatcher.add_handler(message_handler)

# Start the Telegram bot
updater.start_polling()
```

The error :

```
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'
```

I don't know how to fix this, because I've already see many solution but it tell me to update telegram-bot.
is there any solution to this? I've already upgrade telegram-bot but still error.

Comment: did you try the below method?

Answer (score 1):

I think `'dispatcher'` is no longer used in version `20.0a0`

If you want to use your code then you can downgrade as:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot==13.3
```

If you are using `v20` then you have to build your application differently and you have to use `async` functions.